# UIAlert erroneous behaviour

Tags: cocoa-touch

// Tratamento de eventos: caso o utilizador clique numa das células da tabela
Hello again guys,
I was trying to display a UIAlertView to show the summary of a 'Movie' object i have stored and my idea was to show two buttons in it if i had the movie's website stored, or just to show one if the movie didn't have one.

Oddly enough, i'm getting not one, not two, but 3 very different UIAlertViews!

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *ShinraTensei = (@"%@ \n", [[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Sumario]);

    if([[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] WebSite] != nil)
    {
    //  NSLog(@"Nulo");
        UIAlertView* myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TituloFilme] message:ShinraTensei delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
        [myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
        [myAlertView show];
        [myAlertView release];
            myAlertView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* myAlertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TituloFilme] message:ShinraTensei delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"LOL" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        CGAffineTransform myTransform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
        [myAlertView2 setTransform:myTransform2];

        [myAlertView2 show];
        [myAlertView2 release];
            myAlertView = nil;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: If you can't see the picture embeded in this post, please visit:  [http://i41.tinypic.com/2vc9hg9.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Mm4.png)

Comment: Hal, legal ver outro brasileiro fazendo iphone apps!

Answer (score 1):

The first dialog is the standard UIAlertView. The second I can only guess, but I would assume it's when you have too much message text, and it looks different to signal the user that they can scroll the message. The third is UIAlertView with just a title and no message at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the pic?
It's here if you can't: http://i41.tinypic.com/2vc9hg9.jpg

Comment: You should put this information in the main question, not as a follow-up answer. I added this to the question, you should delete this answer since it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

So what is your actual question? I love screenshots as much as the next person, but I don't see a question anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the logic here is good.  Youi are most likely having a problem with your data model.

I'm guessing that the value of [[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TituloFilme] message:ShinraTensei] is nil, in the cases where you are seeing the third type of dialog.